# In a triangle with sides $|AB| = 33$, $|AC| = 21$ and $|BC| = n$ we place point $D$ on $AB$ and $E$ on $AC$ so that $|AD|=|DE|=|EC|=m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, triangles

Find all natural numbers n for which: in a triangle with sides $|AB| = 33$, $|AC| = 21$ and $|BC| = n$ we can place point $D$ on $AB$ and point $E$ on $AC$ such that $|AD| = |DE| = |EC| = m$, where $m$ is also a natural number.

Attempt: I saw that $m=21$ satisfied the condition, so $n$ can be any natural number between $13$ and $53$ by Triangle Inequality theorem. Is this correct?

Comment: $m=21$ is a very particular case ($A=E$) but it indeed satisfies your constraints for any $n$. But I think $n=12$ should be excluded.

Comment: Yes n can be any natural number between 13 (not 12) and 53 by Triangle Inequality theorem. Is this ok, because my explanation is a bit short?

Comment: Hmm, maybe the question meant $B \neq D \neq A$ and $C \neq E \neq A$...

Comment: We can probably assume that, but it wasn't explicitly wrtitten in our test exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case, I found another possible solution: $n=30$ and $m=11$.

Let $\angle BAC=\alpha$. Then from the cosine rule applied to triangles $ABC$ and $ADE$ we have (for $m\ne21$):
$$
\cos\alpha={21-m\over 2m}={33^2+21^2-n^2\over2\cdot 33\cdot 21},
$$
that is:
$$
m={14553\over2223-n^2}.
$$
It's easy to check that the only integer solution for $13\le n\le53$ is the one given above.